# How to show an error message after publishing a post?

Tags: wp-admin, hooks, publish, post-editor, errors

I'm using the `transition_post_status` hook to perform some operations after publishing a post. In some conditions I would like to show an error message in a red box under "Edit Post" and above "Post published":

[image: Post pushlished]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use that hook. [Here's why](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_transition_post_status)

Try something like this using [admin_notices](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices).

```
function wpsites_admin_notice() {
$screen = get_current_screen();
if( 'post' == $screen->post_type
&& 'edit' == $screen->base ){
?>
<div class="error">
    <p><?php _e( 'Updated Demo Message!', 'wpsites' ); ?></p>
</div>
<?php
}}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wpsites_admin_notice' );
```

Untested.

Comment: Great! But how can I figure out in the `wpsites_admin_notice` function what is the error that has occurred?

Comment: This simply shows you how to display the message. To work out any errors is another question which you should ask or change your original question.

Comment: I've asked a [new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133683/use-admin-notices-to-show-errors), but it was marked as duplicate of this. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: You could change debug from FALSE to TRUE in your wp-config.php but not sure what errors you are trying to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

```
add_settings_error(
    'myUniqueIdentifyer',
    esc_attr( 'settings_updated' ),
    $message,
    $type
);
```

Check

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_error