# How should I handle errors within a plugin?

Tags: plugins, errors

Building my first serious attempt of a Wordpress plugin. I'm not sure how I should handle errors. **I really just want to give the user some kind of message that the variable is wrong** instead of throwring an error that makes the whole site not to work.

Inside a class it looks like this:

```
public function set_selectedcurrencies($currencies = null) {
    if ($currencies === null) {
        throw new Exception('No default currencies set');
    }
    if (!is_array($currencies)) {
        throw new Exception('Currencies must be an array existing of two default currencies, default from and default to');
    }
    $this->last_currencies = $currencies;
 }
```

If you then do like this:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->set_selectedcurrencies(234);
```

The whole site would not work because an exception (currencies must be an array existing of two default currencies, default from and default to) is thrown and I don't want that.

So how should I handle this?

**UPDATE**

**I don't want the "end user**" to have to do something like this for my error-handling to work:

```
try {
$foo->set_selectedcurrencies( 5345 );
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Would it be better just to return an error message from the function like this and let the programmer that uses the plugin to do something about it?

```
public function set_selectedcurrencies($currencies = null) {
        if ($currencies === null) {
            return 'No default currencies set';
        }
        if (!is_array($currencies)) {
            return 'Currencies must be an array existing of two default currencies, default from and default to';
        }
        $this->last_currencies = $currencies;
     }
```

**UPDATE2:**

I've figured out what I was looking for. Maybe my question was misleading somehow, but it would be ok to show messages only in admin - section because this error should only be for a guidance for the programmer that implements the plugin.

I've found this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices and made it into "**class-style**":

```
class FOO {

private $errormessage;

public function error_notice() {
    $message = $this->errormessage;
    echo"<div class=\"error\"> <p>$message</p></div>"; 
}

public function set_selectedcurrencies($currencies = null) {
    if ($currencies === null) {
        $this->errormessage = 'No default currencies set';
        add_action( 'admin_notices', array($this,'error_notice' ) ); 
        return;
    }

    if (!is_array($currencies)) {
        $this->errormessage = 'Currencies must be an array existing of two default currencies, default from and default to';
        add_action( 'admin_notices', array($this,'error_notice' ) ); 
        return;
    }

    //default currencies in format currency1, currency2 (USD, EUR)
    $this->last_currencies = $currencies;
}
```

}

I hope this helps anyboy/someone that stumble upon the same issue!

Comment: Don't use exceptions, or wrap the calls in a `try{}catch($e){}` statement and produce error messages.

Comment: @toscho - look at update

Comment: you probably looking for something like http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133674/how-to-show-an-error-message-after-publishing-a-post

Comment: @MarkKaplun - You were absolutely right, but I guess you maybe did not my "update2" ? :-)

Comment: If you figured it out then you should add it as an answer. Answering your own questions is great